# Is there anything similar to `svn info` in clearcase?

Tags: svn, repository, clearcase

Some time ago, I worked with Subversion and I know `svn info` command, but now I need something similar in ClearCase.

What would be the ClearCase equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general [svn info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) generates information that you could find in ClearCase with [`cleartool describe`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-9).

You can apply `cleartool describe` to various ClearCase element (a file or folder, a vob, Attributes, version labels, or both, which are attached to a particular version, Hyperlinks attached to a particular object, ...)

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Could you tell me if there is anyway to use `describe` command through Clear Case plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: @Alavaros yes, this is generally done through the contextual menu entry "properties".